# Switching tab doesn't refresh tab contents

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc

I am trying to make a simple weather app using bloc. Right now I am facing a problem where switching tabs doesn't refresh the contents of my tab views.

This is my home screen with my custom bottom navigation bar

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _itemList = [
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.location_solid, size: 25)),
    const BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.square_list, size: 25))
  ];
  var _pageList = [CurrentLocationScreen(), SavedLocationsScreen()];

  _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) => _pageList.elementAt(_currentIndex)),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 150,
                  child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: const Color(0xccffffff)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.house_fill,
                                color: _currentIndex == 0
                                    ? CupertinoColors.activeBlue
                                    : CupertinoColors.systemGrey),
                            onTap: () => _onItemTapped(0),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart_fill,
                                color: _currentIndex == 1
                                    ? CupertinoColors.systemRed
                                    : CupertinoColors.systemGrey),
                            onTap: () => _onItemTapped(1),
                          )
                        ],
                      ))))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is one of my tab screens

What I don't understand is whenever I switch to any tab, the contents on that tab do not refresh.
I found a workaround by adding events to initState() but that kinda defeats the purpose of bloc. Could anyone point out what the problem with my implementation is? I think it has has something to do with bloc not detecting new state after switching tabs, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide minimal snippet and `_onItemTapped` method

Comment: Thanks for replying. Its _onItemTapped(int index) {setState() {_currentIndex = index;}}.

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` format will be

```dart
setState(
  () {
    ///here your jobs
  },
);
```

```dart
  _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This still doesnt work for me. I tried creating a new page which displays a new random number every time I switch to that tab and it worked perfectly. I suspect the above problem has something to do with bloc not being able to tell the difference between 2 instances of CalculatedState above.

Comment: oh , use method instead instead of variable for this `_pageList() => [...]` and use  and use `_pageList().elementAt(_currentIndex))` this will rebuild the list. if it fails, feel free to rollback the question with minimal snippet